# Is the forgiveness that Jesus mandates in the Parable of the Unforgiving Servant at Matthew 18:21-35 only extended to repentant believers?

Tags: matthew

If one believes that Jesus is speaking to the same circumstance in Luke 17:3 (which appears to be the case), one would seem to be forced to conclude such complete forgiveness is only required to be extended to a believer expressing his sincere repentance for the wrong for which he is seeking forgiveness. Otherwise Jesus would be viewed as contradicting Himself.

Comment: Were that the case, then passages such as Matthew 5:43-45 would make little sense; as to Luke 17:3, in Old Testament context, the word brother and sister referred to fellow Israelites: not sure why the New Testament context would be any different.

Answer (score 1):

The question you ask, or rather the *suggested* inference is clearly seen as incorrect - when and or if you correctly analyse this section from Matthew 18.

Peter thought he was being very generous by offering to forgive his brother 7 times in one day, but Jesus said he should forgive him 490 times in one day. But note, *realistically* it would be impossible to have someone sin against us 490 times in one day.

Jesus was *actually* saying that there should be no limit to our forgiveness.
In context, this principle applies to church discipline (Verses 17 and 18). Regardless of how many times we have to discipline our brothers or sisters, if they repent each time (**Luke 17:4**), we are supposed to forgive them and confirm our love unto them (2 Corinthians 2:6-8).

If God expects us to forgive a brother who has trespassed against us *490* times in one day (actually an unlimited number of times), certainly He who is love (1 John 4:8) will do no less with us.

The word “*therefore*,” with which Jesus began this parable, ties this teaching in with His previous statement on forgiving ( Verse 22) and, indeed, on the related topics of church discipline (Verses 15-20) and God’s compassion for the lost (Verses 12-14). This parable simply illustrates what He already said.

The main thrust of this parable is that when people wrong us, we should remember God’s great mercy that He has shown to us and respond in kind (Ephesians 4:32). Any debt that could be owed to us is insignificant compared to the debt of which we have been forgiven. We should have compassion on others just as Christ had on us (Colossians 3:13 and James 2:13).

If we fail to forgive others just as we have been forgiven, then this parable teaches that we can once again become liable for the debt that has been forgiven. This could also illustrate those who have been saved but renounce their faith, become reprobate, and suffer the torments of hell.

It is certain that not every part of this parable can be applied literally, because the lord of this servant commanded this man’s wife and children to be sold as part of the payment of this debt.  - This cannot be applied to the spiritual meaning of this parable in light of the Scriptures’ teaching that every man and woman will receive judgment *for their own sins* - and not another’s (Deuteronomy 24:16, 2 Kings 14:6, Jeremiah 31:29-30, and Ezekiel 18:19-32).

Therefore, caution should be used when drawing conclusions about judgment from this parable. The main point emphasized is the necessity of forgiving others and the consequences if we don’t.

Answer (score 1):

The exemplar of Christian morality and behavior is, obviously, Christ.

It was Christ Himself who, at His point of maximum humiliation and suffering uttered the noble words:

> Luke 23:34 - Jesus said, “Father, forgive them, for they do not know
> what they are doing.” And they divided up his clothes by casting lots.

Note that when Jesus asked forgiveness for His tormentors and executioners, not one had sought forgiveness!  Paul then drives this point home:

- Bear with each other and forgive one another if any of you has a grievance against someone. Forgive as the Lord forgave you.  Col 3:13.
- Be kind and compassionate to one another, forgiving each other, just as in Christ God forgave you.  Eph 4:32.
- Then Peter came and said to Him, “Lord, how often shall my brother sin against me and I forgive him? Up to seven times?” Jesus said to him, “I do not say to you, up to seven times, but up to seventy times seven.  Matt 18:21, 22.  Jesus then illustrates and reinforces His point using the parable of the unmerciful servant in Matt 18:23-35.
- Therefore, confess your sins to each other and pray for each other so that you may be healed.  James 5:16.
- *And forgive us our debts, as we also have forgiven our debtors*.  Matt 6:12.  See also Mark 11:25, Luke 11:4, 1 John 1:9 and the parable of the unmerciful servant in Matt 18:23-35; all these make our reception of the full benefits of God’s forgiveness dependent on our forgiveness of other’s sins against us in some sense.

There is a simple reason for Jesus offering forgiveness despite our failure to ask - as sinners, we cannot even be fully aware of the hideous extent of out sinfulness (Rom 3:10-18).  It immediately follows that we all have sins for which we remain unaware!

After carefully documenting the extent of the sin problem in Rom 3:10-18, Paul concludes his discussion with this:

> Rom 3:23-26 - for **all have sinned** and fall short of the glory of
> God, and **all are justified freely** by his grace through the
> redemption that came by Christ Jesus. God presented Christ as a
> sacrifice of atonement, i through the shedding of his blood—to be
> received by faith. He did this to demonstrate his righteousness,
> because in his forbearance he had left the sins committed beforehand
> unpunished— he did it to demonstrate his righteousness at the present
> time, so as to be just and the one who justifies those who have faith
> in Jesus.

The fact that God forgives does not make a saved person - a cruel sinner can be forgiven and continue to be cruel.  Reformation of the sinner's life can only begin with confession as John ably points out:

> 1 John 1:9 - If we confess our sins, he is faithful and just to
> forgive us our sins and to **cleanse us** from all unrighteousness.

Note that in Rom 3:23-26 - all have sinned and all are freely forgiven.  This is not universal salvation but universal justification, not all will be saved.  However, God does this to demonstrate His justice according to the same verses.

We, as Christians, must aspire to be just as gracious according to Col 3:13 and Eph 4:32.

Comment: It's also important to remember that, despite the example of "turning the other cheek", forgiveness doesn't have to mean that life should continue as before.  One should forgive other people's debts, whether one thinks they deserve it or not, and one should bear no resentment or malice toward that person, but if the person isn't sorry and repentant,  it is okay to remember that this person doesn't repay debts and to refuse to make further loans.

Comment: @RayButterworth - I fully agree.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see no such bifurcation of law of God for the believers and unbelievers. The bible says repeatedly that God will judge everyone with the same standards, the Jews and Gentiles; believers and unbelievers alike, based on their works they did. The phrase **whoever** applies universally, and not to the believers alone. Consider how the Good Samaritan was justified, and how the Gentiles are justified by their works without the law in Romans 2. The judgment of God is for all mankind.

> **[Matt 7:21-27 ESV]** ​“Not everyone who says to me, ‘Lord, Lord,’ will enter the kingdom of heaven, but the one who does the will of my Father who is in heaven. ​On that day many will say to me, ‘Lord, Lord, did we not prophesy in your name, and cast out demons in your name, and do many mighty works in your name?’ ​And then will I declare to them, ‘I never knew you; depart from me, you workers of lawlessness.’ ​“Everyone then who hears these words of mine and does them will be like a wise man who built his house on the rock. And the rain fell, and the floods came, and the winds blew and beat on that house, but it did not fall, because it had been founded on the rock. And everyone who hears these words of mine and does not do them will be like a foolish man who built his house on the sand. And the rain fell, and the floods came, and the winds blew and beat against that house, and it fell, and great was the fall of it.”

Answer (score 0):

Matthew 18:

> 21Then Peter came to Jesus and asked, “Lord, how many times shall I forgive my **brother** (Br) who sins against me? Up to seven times?”
>
> 22Jesus answered, “I tell you, not just seven times, but seventy-seven times!

Is the forgiveness that Jesus mandates in the Parable of the Unforgiving Servant at Matthew 18:21-35 only extended to repentant believers?

Let R = Br repents.
F = I forgive Br.

Proof by contradiction:

Assume C1: ¬R → ¬F
i.e., if Br does not repent, then I do not forgive Br.

Jesus says in Matthew 6:

> 15
> But if you do not forgive others their sins, your Father will not forgive your sins.

Let F1 = The Father forgive your sins.

Matthew 6:15 says C2: ¬F → ¬F1

Combine C1 and C2,
¬R → ¬F ∧ ¬F → ¬F1
⇒ ¬R → ¬F1

Therefore, if Br does not repent, then the Father does not forgive me.
This is ridiculous: Br sins against me and refuses to repent, so the Father does not forgive me because Br refuses to repent!?

The assumption is false. Its negation is true: Br does not repent and I still forgive him.

OP: Otherwise Jesus would be viewed as contradicting Himself.

Can you present the two propositions that are contradictory?

Is the forgiveness that Jesus mandates in the Parable of the Unforgiving Servant at Matthew 18:21-35 only extended to repentant believers?

no, according to first-order logic.